# Statements in Kotlin constructor

Tags: constructor, initialization, kotlin

Is there a way to mix statements (like print statements) and member assignments in Kotlin?
Here is an example of what I would like to do (in Java):

```
class MySystem {
    ComponentA componentA;
    ComponentB componentB;

    public MySystem() {
        System.out.println("Initializing components");
        this.componentA = new ComponentA();
        System.out.println("Constructed componentA");
        this.componentB = new ComponentB();
        System.out.println("Constructed componentB");
    }
}
```

Grateful for any input, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is: use the [`init` blocks](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors). The `init` blocks and property initializers are executed in the same order as they appear in the code:

```
class MyClass {
    init { println("Initializing components") }

    val componentA = ComponentA()
    init { println("Constructed componentA") }

    val componentB = ComponentB()
    init { println("Constructed componentA") }
}
```

Or, alternatively, separate the declaration and initialization:

```
class MyClass {
    val componentA: ComponentA
    val componentB: ComponentB

    init {
        println("Initializing components")
        componentA = ComponentA()
        println("Constructed componentA")
        componentB = ComponentB()
        println("Constructed componentB");
    }
}
```

This will also work with secondary constructors.

Comment: Thank you :) I had not planned to answer it myself, but once I had written the question down, I could paste the code into IntelliJ and it was translated to Kotlin.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the fields and use an init block:

```
internal class MySystem {
    val componentA: ComponentA
    val componentB: ComponentB

    init {
        println("Initializing components")
        this.componentA = ComponentA()
        println("Constructed componentA")
        this.componentB = ComponentB()
        println("Constructed componentB")
    }
}
```